# update data from a table using a patch REST service in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I appreciate if you can help me please.
Obtain the data from a table and through its id, take it as a reference in a Patch-type Rest service, send the data in the body.
I am new to azure data factory.
Thanks

I have a table that contains the following columns `id, field1, field2, field3.`
The idea is for a PATCH method on the endpoint `https://api.localhost.com/objects/contac/{id}`
to be able to update the fields of the columns by the id that I have in the table, the body that the endpoint takes is

```
{
   "properties":
   {
     "data1": "field1",
     "data2": "field2",
     "data3": "field3"
}
}
```

I have tried with an activity such as copy data, through a pipeline and I have not been able to, I am new to azure data factory.

Comment: Can you provide what error you are facing when you tried and expected result?

Comment: This is the error, but I don't know how to map the id in the endpoint
```Detalles del error
Código de error
RestCallFailedWithClientError
Tipo de error
Problema de configuración de usuario
Detalles
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=RestCallFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Rest call failed with client error, status code 405 MethodNotAllowed, please check your activity settings.
Request URL: https://api.localhost.com/objects/contac/.
Response: ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
Origen
Canalización```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Take a `lookup` activity to get the rows of your table with id and field values.

[image]

- This returns each row as an object inside an array. So you can iterate through this data using for each loop with items value as:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

- Inside foreach loop, you can use a `web activity`. The following would be the dynamic content that you can use to build URL and Body for `Patch` method:

```
URL: 
https://api.localhost.com/objects/contac/@{item().id}

Body: 
{
"properties":
{
"data1": "@{item().field1}",
"data2": "@{item().field2}",
"data3": "@{item().field3}"
}
}
```

[image]

- When you run this pipeline, you should be able to get what you need. Copy data does not fit your requirement and the REST api linked service does not support PATCH method as well.

NOTE: My pipeline failed as I don't have a REST API for patch service.